# Is it possible to delete a word in the forward direction with zsh?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, zle

I found that I was able to implement <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> in bash using `"^[[3;5~": shell-kill-word` inside my `~/.inputrc`. 
However, zsh does not use inputrc, and ZLE has no `shell-kill-word` option that I can find in the [doc](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html).

Is this possible? We can surely do it with some custom functions right? What might such a function look like?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that what i'm looking for is actually just `kill-word`. So `bindkey '\e[3;5~' kill-word` actually just works.

Comment: This is bound to `Esc+d` by default.